# Why the output voltage of this IC cannot reach higher?

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit

I'm trying to design a remote control. But during the process of design, I found that the output voltage of IC TPS40057 of the switch can just reach to less than 6V. The simplified application diagram of this IC is in the following： [image]
I don't know why it can't reach higher value. Can anybody answer me why?

For further reference, the datasheet is at http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps40057.pdf.

Any answer will be highly appreciated!

Comment: "Any answer will be highly appreciated!". How will you show your appreciation?

Comment: You leave a lot of things unclear. Have you build this already and can you not reach 6 V or are you asking about the capabilities of this IC ? What it can do is in the datasheet, if that does not fit your needs, use a different IC. When used properly (Vin is high enough, load not too high, proper components used) this IC **can** reach 6 V easily.

Comment: Ah,thank you..I have built this already but it cannot reach 6v, I saw the max output voltage of this IC is 6v in the datasheet, so I'm just wondering why it cannot reach...

Comment: If you want us to check, why your design can't reach your desired voltage, you have to supply more information. I.e. the values of all components used. Best thing is, you draw a new schematic with all values given.

Comment: *I saw the max output voltage of this IC is 6v in the datasheet* Then you misunderstood the datasheet, it says that the maximum voltage on VFB, SS/SD, SYNC is 6V. There is no maximum output voltage specified.

Comment: You might at least tell us the input voltage.

Comment: This part, besides being obsolete, is also intended for high-amperage buck converter applications -- it requires external MOSFETs, and their example design is for an 8A supply.  This is totally incongruous with a remote control.  Why did you select this part?  What are your input and output voltage and current requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Only COMP, RT, SS/SD pins are limited to 6 volts (as stated in the absolute maximum ratings table in the data sheet). There is no reason why the output voltage from this buck regulator can't be any value that is within the range 0.7 volts to 35 volts (see link supplied by SteveG).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe I had some misunderstanding before, since I'm really new to this field.. I think I should read more related materials to figure this out.

Comment: @Lumersfly any reason why you're using the TPS40057? It is an old part, TI already state "not suitable for new designs", there are much better and simpler parts available.

Comment: @Lumersfly [This](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS40057/description) gives Vout(max) as 35V.

Comment: @SteveG thanks for uncovering the specific upper limit. I shall adjust my answer.

Comment: So do you have any other recommendations of this kind of IC, apart from TPS40057. Because I am new to this kind of design,so I just choose one in http://www.kynix.com/Search/TPS40057.html

Comment: You choose a part because it suits the target application and this isn't specified. Your question is answered BTW.